# QuickBook Desktop

Tags: php-7, magento2.2.3, sales, cloud

Can we sync data from quickbooks desktop to Magento 2, Specifically If an invoice was Marked paid / or partial paid in Quickbooks will It sync that data up to magento 2?

I want to synchronise invoice,edit order status , order tracking details and RMA(Returns) from quickbook desktop to magento 2.

The default features of our QuickBooks Desktop Integration does not support this requirement.

Can you please guide me on this requirement?It would be a great help.
After searching over net I came across this link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939789/fetch-invoices-from-quickbooks-with-the-help-of-api-using-php

But I am not clear where to write the code given in the above link.

I have tried below code in app/code/Magenest/QuickBooksDesktop/Model/Connector.php

```
function _quickbooks_invoice_import_request($requestID, $user, $action, $ID, $extra, &$err, $last_action_time, $last_actionident_time, $version, $locale)
{

    $attr_iteratorID = '';
    $attr_iterator = ' iterator="Start" ';
    if (empty($extra['iteratorID']))
    {
        $last = _quickbooks_get_last_run($user, $action);
        _quickbooks_set_last_run($user, $action);           

        _quickbooks_set_current_run($user, $action, $last);
    }
    else
    {
        $attr_iteratorID = ' iteratorID="' . $extra['iteratorID'] . '" ';
        $attr_iterator = ' iterator="Continue" ';

        $last = _quickbooks_get_current_run($user, $action);
    }

    $xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <?qbxml version="' . $version . '"?>
        <QBXML>
            <QBXMLMsgsRq onError="stopOnError">
                <InvoiceQueryRq ' . $attr_iterator . ' ' . $attr_iteratorID . ' requestID="' . $requestID . '">
                    <MaxReturned>' . QB_QUICKBOOKS_MAX_RETURNED . '</MaxReturned>
                    <ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
                        <FromModifiedDate>' . $last . '</FromModifiedDate>
                    </ModifiedDateRangeFilter>
                    <IncludeLineItems>true</IncludeLineItems>
                    <OwnerID>0</OwnerID>
                </InvoiceQueryRq>   
            </QBXMLMsgsRq>
        </QBXML>';

    return $xml;
}
```

which did not help.
Can anyone guide me in this.